# Server config issue with Python

Tags: php, python, cgi

I've tried to run a simple "hello world" python script but in my browser it shows plain text and doesn't run.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print ""

    print "Hello, World"
```

But if I run it using a php exec function, the "Hello World" script runs.

```
    <?php
    echo exec('python hello.py');
    ?>
```

What am I missing to make the .py files run normally?
It's apache on Linux

Comment: It could be a typo; try capitalizing the T in Content-Type.

Comment: Welcome to SO, user2843577.

Answer (score 0):

php exec:

> Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.

[documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

you need to pass a variable output to save the input or your exec will return the last line only

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that our server needed an extra space after calling the shebang. Two line breaks and the code failed, add a third and it ran.